# Removing extra class from CSS

Tags: css, html

The stylesheet have multiple references to specific ".wiki-content" class, i.e.

```
    .wiki-content ul,.wiki-content ol,.wiki-content dl {
    padding-top:0;
    margin-top:0;
        }

    .wiki-content a,.wiki-content a:link,.wiki-content a:visited {
    text-decoration:underline;
        }

    .wiki-content p,.wiki-content table,.view .wiki-content .cell:first-child,.content-preview .wiki-content .cell:first-child {
    padding:0;
        }

    .wiki-content table.confluenceTable {
    border-collapse:collapse;
        }
```

but HTML code have only one reference the this class, in body:  `<body class="mceContentBody wiki-content fullsize">` Further html have no any references to this class: the p, li, ul, a, tags have no .wiki-content class selector specified. I checked page using CSS Usage plugin, but it does not mark these .wiki-content CSS selectors as "Unseen", they all shown as green (legit) ones. Can I safely remove this **.wiki-content** class from CSS stylesheet? The page generated by Atlassian Confluence Wiki system, but I use a copy saved locally for offline use.

Comment: Just because the HTML doesn't contain the class doesn't mean an element added to the DOM via javascript or a page generated in a server side language (such as PHP) won't use the class.

Comment: Back the file up, delete the CSS and see if the page breaks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the parent element, if it has the class then it probably NOT safe to remove it.

```
<div class="wiki-content">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

This would apply the style following style to the `UL` element

```
.wiki-content ul,.wiki-content ol,.wiki-content dl {
padding-top:0;
margin-top:0;
    }
```

The `.wiki-content ul` means to apply the style to any children `UL` elements of the element that has the class defined.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a div, I just used that as an example. In your sample, you are definitely using those classes and they  are being applied to UL and other elements. Just add background:red to the class to see easily see them. The style is being applied to child elements of the element that has the class.

Comment: It looks like a `<body class="mceContentBody wiki-content fullsize">` is a parent element in this case. Is this why CSS Usage show `.wiki-content` class as Seen(green)? Here is live page:[sample](http://goo.gl/TsZb0z)

Comment: If I remove .wiki-content class from CSS, it will not have any effect on html appearance, as style will be applied **directly** to p, ul, etc tags, like this: `ul, ol, dl {
padding-top:0;  
margin-top:0;
}` not via parent element. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If there is no HTML in your site/app that has that class, you can safely remove it as the CSS is not being used anyway. I'd recommend using your text editors find functionality to double check that it isn't included anywhere though before you do remove it.

One thing to consider though, assuming you didn't write this CSS, maybe check with the developer who wrote it to see what the reasoning is behind it.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is always to back up the stylesheet, then delete the lines from the current stylesheet and see if it negatively affects anything on the page.

That being said, if CSS Usage is showing the classes as seen, it's likely they are being used somewhere. But even if that's the case, it doesn't necessarily mean deleting the styles is really going to negatively affect your site.

Answer (score 0):

Being that the class is on the body, it is probably being used to name-space the page. There may be other non wiki pages that use the same style sheet, but have different styles on the same tag or class. Name-spacing the entire page allows you to target only the styles that are appended with .wiki-content - Just a guess but I think that's what's happening.

End of the day, I would leave it as you may create some colliding styles if you remove it.